# Hiding an MFC dialog box

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Ok so I am using this code to hide the taskbar icon of a dialog based MFC application(VC++). The taskbar icon and the dialog box hide whenever I click on the cross or the close buttons. But I can’t get this one thing right. Whenever I hit the close or the cross button from title bar, the dialog box first flickers and shows a sort of intermediate dialog box and then hides. This is very annoying. I am posting my code here after two days of vain effort. So guys please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
void CMyAppDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
  // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
  CWnd* pWnd;
  pWnd = AfxGetMainWnd();

  RemoveTaskbarIcon(pWnd);
  pWnd->ModifyStyle(WS_VISIBLE, 0);
  mVisible = FALSE;
}

BOOL CMyAppDlg::RemoveTaskbarIcon(CWnd* pWnd)
{
  LPCTSTR pstrOwnerClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(0);

  // Create static invisible window
  if (!::IsWindow(mWndInvisible.m_hWnd))
   {
    if (!mWndInvisible.CreateEx(0, pstrOwnerClass, _T(""),
             WS_POPUP,
             CW_USEDEFAULT,
             CW_USEDEFAULT, 
             CW_USEDEFAULT, 
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
             NULL, 0))
      return FALSE;
   }

   pWnd->SetParent(&mWndInvisible);

  return TRUE;
}
```

Here are the screen shots of dialog box. When I press the close or cross button, the dialog box which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpweT.png)  in the first place turns into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b03BZ.png)  for like less than half a second and then disappears (hides).

Comment: Change the window style if you don't want the dialog in the taskbar. Don't mess with invisible parent windows (children of windows that aren't visible... aren't visible). Look at WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW.

Comment: Also you should not toggle WS_VISIBLE directly. Use ShowWindow(SW_HIDE).

Answer (score 22):

If you show your dialog using `CDialog::DoModal()` the framework will make sure your dialog is shown. There is only one way to prevent a modal dialog from being shown:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CHiddenDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    m_visible = FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

void CHiddenDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS FAR* lpwndpos) 
{
    if (!m_visible)
        lpwndpos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;

    CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't hide app when you press Alt + Tab in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an obvious thing, but what happens when you do the hide before you reparent the dialog? Also what if you don't directly modify the window style but use `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`?

Finally, have you tried switching the dialog's window style to `WS_CHILD` before calling `SetParent()` and/or maybe moving it out of the client area so that the window isn't shown any more (`MoveWindow(-1000, -1000)` or something like that).

Comment: Unless you have sample code showing it will work, it is highly unlikely it will work. Many people, including MFC experts, have tried. Study the MFC source code before speculating. I would explain why this response won't work but it has been many years since I tried to solve the problem.

Comment: So you don't have a clue either yet you feel the need to post a smartass response to a 6 year old question? Why even bother?

Comment: Look again. After posting my comment I proceeded to copy the answer I have had in [Hiding a Dialog Initially](http://simplesamples.info/MFC/DlgPosChanged.aspx). A good reason to post the comment I did is to save people some time.

Comment: Many years ago I spent much time, including studying the MFC source code, to solve the problem of hiding modal dialogs initially. The main problem is that intermingled among other code is code that explicitly shows modal dialogs and overriding that requires replacing a relatively large portion of the code.

Comment: You did say "moving it out of the client area" but you were not sure. That was close but not quite what is actually needed.

Comment: Well then why not just post a new answer instead of ragging on someone who actually tried to help OP when he needed it? Are you in a habit of gping around picking on people to point out the exact ways their answers aren't quite precise enough?

Comment: I get dumped on in worse ways than this. Attempts to help often get down-votes. Some members down-vote and I don't know who and I can't respond. And stackoverflow wants useful answers, not speculation, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think Paul DiLascia recommended the following. This is for modal dialogs only.

The following code can be put in OnInitDialog to move the dialog off-screen. You will need to implement a method for moving it back on-screen when appropriate.

```
CRect DialogRect;
GetWindowRect(&DialogRect);
int DialogWidth = DialogRect.Width();
int DialogHeight = DialogRect.Height();
MoveWindow(0-DialogWidth, 0-DialogHeight, DialogWidth, DialogHeight);
```

The answer from l33t looks good and is probably better but this is an alternative.