# Hide an MFC dialog window

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have written an MFC dialog based application which is launched by some another application. For now, I have not added any code. It is just the default files that I got. The other application can successfully launch my application.

I am trying to hide the window of my application when the other application launches it.

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    CMyAppDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;        

    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();

    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    { 
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I tried to use:

```
dlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)
```

but it still does not hide the window.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Does your `CMyAppDlg` inherit from `CDialog`?

Comment: Thanks. It inherits from `CDialogEx`,

Comment: Is your dialog modeless ? CMyAppDlg will not show anything. If you call dlg.DoModal(), then the code will not reach the ShowWindow just after it.

Comment: @ixe013, Thanks for your reply. I am calling `dlg.DoModal()`. Please look at the updated code.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Hiding an MFC dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255106/hiding-an-mfc-dialog-box)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding an MFC dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255106/hiding-an-mfc-dialog-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to the above issue. The InitInstance code should be as follows:

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    CMyAppDlg dlg;
    dlg.Create(IDD_MyAppUI_DIALOG,NULL);
    dlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    dlg.UpdateWindow();
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Won't dlg be destroyed just when leaving InitInstance scope ?

Comment: Yes, it will be destroyed. So this code will eventually crash. The solution proposed by @chintan would work if the dialog was created on the heap.

Comment: Did you simply try dlg.ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZED); ?

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Hiding a *non-modal* dialog is a no-brainer, obviously. The problem lies in the logic if `DoModal()`. Hence, the workaround found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255106/hiding-an-mfc-dialog-box).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you have another problem someplace.

If you create a totally new, blank MFC app (Visual Studio 2010) then in App::InitInstance, setting SW_HIDE rather than SW_SHOW **does** cause the resultant window to be hidden.

```
BOOL CProj1App::InitInstance()
{

// boilerplate code
      . . . 

// The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);   // WORKS!
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it builds perfectly, but when I run it, it breaks after `m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);` is executed.

Comment: In `ShowWindow()`, it breaks after `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));`

Comment: @chintan, I agree, I can reproduce what you say. The code above works when you use the wizard to create a "single document" application, but not when you create a "dialog" application. I would suggest creating a "single document" application and looking at how the boilerplate implementations of InitInstance differ.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I will try to create a "Signle Document" application and get back with response. Thanks again.

Comment: I gave it a go, but "Single Documented" application would not be accepted, it has to be dialog based. There should be some sort of work around for dialog based applications.

Comment: @chintan - I repeat... look at how the boilerplate implementations of InitInstance differ. I am **not** suggesting you use a SingleDocument for your soultion. I am suggesting that you look at the generated code for SingleDocument to work out why your solution does not work.

Comment: OK, I can hide the window with single document. Let me see what is different.

Comment: found the issue. Please have a look at the solution.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you call `DoModal` your dialog is doomed to be shown. There is only one workaround that successfully avoids focus/flicker problems. See my answer here: [Hiding an MFC dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255106/hiding-an-mfc-dialog-box)

Hence, your code should look like this:

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance() 
{ 
    CMyAppDlg dlg;
    dlg.SetVisible(FALSE); // Sets m_visible flag to FALSE.

    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;         

    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal(); 

    if (nResponse == IDOK) 
    { 
    } 
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL) 
    {  
    } 

    return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't hide app when you press Alt + Tab in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You must hide the dialog from the inside.

1. Overload OnInitDialog
2. Call CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()
3. Hide your window and return

Here is the code

```
BOOL CMyAppDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL result = CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    this->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

    return result;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

There is [another method with a sentinel value](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1724/Some-handy-dialog-box-tricks-tips-and-workarounds), YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me address some issues with previous solutions.

**chintan s:**
Indeed dialog will be killed when function goes out of scope. It would be a valid solution if dialog was declared as a member variable of the app class.

**Vikky:**
No need to call Windows API, since dialog is derived from CWnd and it inherits ShowWindow member that take only one parameter: show command.

**ixe013:**
This solution will work, however, before dialog hides, it will flash, since ShowWindow is called before OnInitDialog is called.

**Pete:**
This won’t work, since, modal dialog starts before m_pMainWnd has any value assigned to it.

**The solution is pointed by ixe013.**

This is so far the only solution that works but you will have to declare **member** variable in you dialog class, as described in the article.

Answer (score 0):

The showWindow method has 2 variable.

- handle of window
- nCmdShow(Controls how the window is to be shown)

  **BOOL WINAPI ShowWindow(
   *In*  HWND hWnd,
        *In*  int nCmdShow
      );**

  HWND hWnd = GetSafeHwnd();

  ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_HIDE);

See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it says `m_visible` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks again, but now it says `GetSafeHwnd()` is udnefined.

Comment: Have You include Afxwin.h header file

Comment: There is no need to call the GLOBAL function ::ShowWindow(...). Using this->ShowWindow(...) is just an wrapper around it.