# Make Non-GUI server application in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, mfc, serversocket

I did a project of Server Socket in Visual studio in C++ MFC based. Now, after debugging the project, server GUI opens, then after clicking on the *CONNECT* button on server GUI, you can connect the clients to that server and so on.

Now I want to use that server exe file in some other computer. So that whenever that computer starts, that server exe automatically starts. so for this i need to disable the connect button, so that after debugging, server GUi opens and connected automatically. But  i don't want that server GUI opens in another computer in autostart as well. i want to disable that server GUI.

I got an idea of modalless dialog to work on it. Is it good or what approach should I use ?

Comment: Please don't misuse the caps lock button - especially for titles.

Comment: If your program is suffering from [magic pushbuttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton), a ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) could achieve what you want without refactoring the code. However, a proper solution would involve separating GUI from core, like @Lol4t0 suggested.

Comment: i didnot use ShowWindow in my project. I used modal dialog. may be you are talking about modeless dialog. IF so, then should i need to make a totally new project based on modeless dialog ? And how to seperate GUI from core. I dont have this idea. kindly tell plz

Comment: ShowWindow() simply controls the visibility of a window (a dialog is a window too). As for refactoring, move your socket server code to its own class if that's not the case already and use it in your CWinApp based class or directly in WinMain. To debug it, you could create another project that uses your class in a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only professional and stable solution of such an application is, to splitt it in a console part, which you put under the control of service control and a gui part wich the user can start when he wants.

I tried solutions like yours and so I can tell you from my own experience, that you will face a lot of problems.

However, a possible solution would be to hide the window and [lay the app down to systray](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74/Adding-Icons-to-the-System-Tray) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856926/hide-an-mfc-dialog-window) is a very interesting discussion about hinding windows.

Additionaly I have two good advices in case of MFC:

1. Never ever just "copy-past" code without to know what MFC is doing in the background (Win32api).
2. Do not use MFC. Have a closer look at QT or wxWidges when you need windows, to shortcut encapsulation of win32api also have a look at boost library. It is realy worth the time you spend on!

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to separate GUI part and server part of your application. Ideally, if your server is *actually* a server, you should start it as *service*. Then you will have separate GUI tool to control it.

Another approach is to have command line argument that determines whether server should be started with GUI enabled or disabled.

Comment: i dont want to separate anything. i have successfully build the server socket project that has GUI. i just need to disable that GUi, means that after debugging this project, server.exe should run in the background rather showing GUI. i hope it is clear now

Comment: @Nabeel, Then use `another approach`, but how are you going to _control_ the application? After you start it without GUI and without any remote control interface, you will lose the control of that application.

Comment: i think,  every computer has autostart files, whenever that computer starts, some of the files automatically starts. i am trying to use exactly that idea, to just copy that server.exe file there in autostart folder, and rest the computer do job on its own.