# ActiveX OLE control not registered, MFC Create function fail

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I have an visual C++ code, that uses MFC and it creates an domodal dialog.
The project was not developed by me, my task being to hide the dialog window.

I have managed to do that, it worked fine for a while, but now when `dlg.Create` is called it return me :

```
CoCreateInstance of OLE control {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed
Result code: 0x80040154
Is the control is properly registered?
```

The message above is not an build error, is an message that pops after the `dlg.Create` fails, so my app will not call `::OnInitDialog()` function.

I have very little experience with MFC and ActiveX controllers, so all my attempts of solving the problem failed.
I have checked the registry entry, the dlls signature and it seems everything ok.

So could you help me or give hints of how should i approach this problem and solve it.

Below I will post the code where the problem pops.

```
CCRViewerDlg  dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;  

int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();

if( dlg.Create( CCRViewerDlg::IDD))
{
    dlg.ShowWindow( SW_HIDE );
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.RunModalLoop();
}
DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about this error code already.  "Is the control properly registered?" invariably answered with "No". SysInternal's ProcMon utility can show you where it looks for the control.  Contact the vendor or author of this control for additional support.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog instance is already created and shown with the `DoModal` call. Then you're trying to create it again - this will lead to all kinds of resource problems.

You need to either show it with DoModal and then hide it from within the dialog code, or don't use DoModal at all.

See similar questions:
[Hide an MFC dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856926/hide-an-mfc-dialog-window) and
[Hiding an MFC dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255106/hiding-an-mfc-dialog-box)